# Trouble animating UILabel alpha in UITableView section footer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I am attempting to animate a subtly throbbing warning label in a `UITableView` footerView, but for some reason, my animation is not, well... animating. The odd thing is the *effect* of the animation (i.e. the end result) is taking affect, but it is neither animating nor looping as it should be. It just immediately appears in the final state, as if it were not in an animation block at all.

Here is the animation I am trying to apply:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,tableView.width, kModPopFooterHeight)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    view.opaque = NO;

    __block UILabel* incompleteLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
    incompleteLabel.height = kModPopFooterHeight - 8.0;
    incompleteLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    incompleteLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    incompleteLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    incompleteLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    incompleteLabel.text = @"Please complete the above section";
    [view addSubview:incompleteLabel];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        incompleteLabel.alpha = 0.1;
    } completion:nil];

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the animate call inside `dispatch_async` and now it magically works.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        incompleteLabel.alpha = 0.1;
    } completion:nil];
});
```

Comment: It also works if you make a custom class for your footer view, and put the animation code in didMoveToSuperview; not sure why that, or your method causes it to work. A timing issue maybe?

Comment: My guess is it has to do with the fact that there were already animations taking place when the code was being executed, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I did some testing, and I think the reason is actually that the label is not in the view hierarchy at the time the animation starts. If I create a label, start the animation, then add the label to its superview (using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with a 0 delay), I see the same problem you did. If you add the label as a subview before starting the animation, it works (or even if you add it after the animation code, but inside the same method, so it seems like the view has to be in the view hierarchy within the same turn of the run loop for the animation to work).

Comment: @rdelmar That actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your animation block to `tableView:didEndDisplayingFooterView:forSection:` method. Don't animate it directly there, just return a view.

Comment: No luck. I don't think that's what I want anyway though. According to the documentation: "Tells the delegate that the specified footer view was removed from the table.".

Comment: Ok. Can you try willDisplay?

Comment: Just trying that now, but it's not being called for some reason.

Comment: Looks like `willDisplayFooterView` is not called when using custom footerViews, leaving `viewForFooterInSection` as the only point I can attach the animation.